# Unable to get lm-sensors to report my fan speeds for Asus Z97-WS

Tags: asus, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I've followed through the basic processes to detect my sensors (nct-6791 chip), yet all I get from sensors is as follows:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +27.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +21.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +24.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

I've checked sensors3.conf, and it has entries for the chip as follows, but it appears to me that sensors either isn't reading the conf, or perhaps I'm missing support for that chip in the kernel.

```
chip "w83627ehf-*" "w83627dhg-*" "w83667hg-*" "nct6775-*" "nct6776-*" "nct6779-*" "nct6791-*"

    label in0 "Vcore"
    label in2 "AVCC"
    label in3 "+3.3V"
    label in7 "3VSB"
    label in8 "Vbat"

    label fan1 "Fan 1"
    label fan2 "CPU fan"
        # The correponding pwm also controls the 'CPU Opt' fan

    label fan3 "Fan 2"
    label fan4 "Fan 3"
    label fan5 "Fan 4"
    label fan6 "CPU fan 2"
        # 'CPU Opt' header


    set in2_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in2_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in3_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in3_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in7_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in7_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in8_min  3.0 * 0.90
    set in8_max  3.3 * 1.10
```

Either way, I'm not savvy enough to know how to proceed next without guidance. I'm comfortable making changes based on instructions, but my ability to dig deep on my own is pretty weak at this point.  I don't want to control speeds, merely report them in my conky dashboard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have this board as well and now that it is primarily running Ubuntu instead of Windows, I finally decided to figure out how to control the fans without using the BIOS UI.

In short;

Boot with lax acpi resource sharing and load the nct6775 driver.

```
grep CMDLINE /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
update-grub
reboot
modprobe nct6775
```

Leave GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT as it is unless you have reasons to change it.

Before doing the lax thing, I could see this error in dmesg after loading the nct6775 module:

```
[84740.224136] nct6775: Enabling hardware monitor logical device mappings.
[84740.224146] nct6775: Found NCT6791D or compatible chip at 0x2e:0x290
[84740.224151] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000295-0x0000000000000296 conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000290-0x0000000000000299 (\_GPE.HWM) (20210331/utaddress-204)
[84740.224156] ACPI: OSL: Resource conflict; ACPI support missing from driver?
```

After, I get these sensors:

```
# sensors
(...)
nct6791-isa-0290
Adapter: ISA adapter
Vcore:                 880.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +1.74 V)
in1:                     1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
AVCC:                    3.38 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+3.3V:                   3.38 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in4:                     1.02 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in5:                     1.99 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in6:                   384.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
3VSB:                    3.41 V  (min =  +2.98 V, max =  +3.63 V)
Vbat:                    3.30 V  (min =  +2.70 V, max =  +3.63 V)
in9:                     1.01 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in10:                    0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
in11:                  824.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in12:                  104.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in13:                   96.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
in14:                  424.00 mV (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)  ALARM
fan1:                   742 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                   558 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                   906 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan6:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
SYSTIN:                 +63.0°C  (high =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
CPUTIN:                 +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, hyst = +75.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN0:               -128.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN1:               -128.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN2:                +35.0°C    sensor = thermistor
AUXTIN3:                +63.0°C    sensor = thermistor
PECI Agent 0:           +50.0°C
PCH_CHIP_CPU_MAX_TEMP:   +0.0°C
PCH_CHIP_TEMP:           +0.0°C
PCH_CPU_TEMP:            +0.0°C
intrusion0:            ALARM
intrusion1:            ALARM
beep_enable:           disabled
(...)
```

And these fan-crontrollers:

```
# find /sys/ -name 'pwm?'
/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm5
/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm3
/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1
/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm4
/sys/devices/platform/nct6775.656/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm2
```

---

You can read this discussion about why the lax acpi parameter is necessary. It is probably safe to use, but be careful. TBH, idk what could go wrong but you can probably research this further.

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204807#c37

> tl;dr - the kernel message you're seeing is correct. Avoiding it requires a new driver to be written. If you *personally* feel safe in ignoring the risks, you can pass the acpi_enforce_resources=lax option, but that can't be the default because it's unsafe in the general case, and so it isn't the solution to the wider problem.

---

When you have that working, use `fancontrol` utility to control the fan speed in auto mode or configure the fan speeds manually with `pwmconfig`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `sensors-detect`. It will detect and update your modules.

I still had to find updated `/etc/sensors3.conf` entries for my chipset on my motherboard.

- http://www.spinics.net/lists/lm-sensors/msg37631.html

However, my asus-isa-0000 also shows 0 speed, but my nct6779 now shows everything correctly.